# How to pick up specific message data from MarketingCloudSDKInboxMessagesDataSource?

Tags: swift, salesforce, salesforce-marketing-cloud

I am using MarketingCloudSDK iOS (v6.0.1) and try to get a specific message from my inbox data source.

But I have a problem when using Inbox feature.

I am reading the document "Track Inbox Message Opens" on the below link.
https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-iOS/inbox/inbox.html

This code become an error.

```
let myInboxMessagesDict = myDataSource[indexPath.row] as? [AnyHashable: Any]
// 'myDataSource' type is 'MarketingCloudSDKInboxMessagesDataSource'.
```

The error message: `Type 'MarketingCloudSDKInboxMessagesDataSource' has no subscript members`.

My question is

- Does MarketingCloudSDKInboxMessagesDataSource have subscript function?
- If it is correct, why can I not access the message data by using IndexPath?

Please tell me the solution.